# What font does Google Material.io use to create icons?

Tags: font-identification, google-material-design

Can the font used for text in Google's icons be downloaded from somewhere? For instance the font used on this icon:

[image]

The icon comes from [Google Material.io](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=fiber_dvr&style=baseline) and the font used in this icon is used on multiple icons. It looks like it is a mono-font but I can't figure out which one.

Comment: That icon is way too small to decipher what font is used.

Comment: Can you also explain which Google icons you're referring to? It's hard to know that the icon "DVR" is a Google icon. It might depend on where the icon came from, was this from Android?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a font behind the text on this image as the image is a vector image of SVG format done by google and the font is used multiple times through out their icons collection. @ZachSaucier.

Comment: The icon is not too small, this is a vector image so the size doesn't matter @AndrewH.
I added a link to the library if you want to see it in a bigger size.

I also added the origin of the icon for more informations

Comment: [This font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat?category=Sans+Serif,Monospace&preview.text=123+URL&preview.text_type=custom) is close from the result but not exactly the good one
May be a mix with [this one](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Gayathri?category=Sans+Serif,Monospace&preview.text=123+URL&preview.text_type=custom)

Comment: The icon example you posted is too small to identify.  You have not posted a vector example, but a tiny raster image. Increase its size before exporting so we can at least see it properly. Also what steps have you taken to identify the font?  There are automated font ID websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the letters are from a font called [FF World One.](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-world/one/)

[image: FF World One]

Some looks like [Super Deluxe Semibold](https://creativemarket.com/GoodCraftSupply/3643692-Super-Deluxe-Display)

[image: Super Deluxe Semibold]

These icons are a font that you can download, so I'm not sure if you're looking for a similar font for other purposes, or trying to recreate the icons.  Given that they ARE created icons, I'm guessing that the letters were modified slightly to fit the look the designer wanted.

Comment: Thanks I will try it and figure out if they need some adjustments to validare your answer.

Comment: I tried it and it is really close to the icon font. I assume they made slight modification to the font when they used it on their icon.
It seems they streched it horizontally a bit.

Comment: Very welcome! Good luck!